# UPS Address Validation API candidate list

Tags: ups

I'm implementing address verification using UPS address validation API (XML format).

And I noticed the following: when I receive response with ambiguous address indicator, candidate list contains street1 field suggestions in a range format, like '1-21 Some street', '2-20 Some street' etc.

Could you please give a hint (or request option) how to receive a candidate list where street1 address number suggestion is not in range format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many companies, including SmartyStreets, have already implemented what you are trying to implement. You can try it out here and use their APIs instead of creating your own. They have autocomplete as well as address verification https://smartystreets.com/demo

Comment: We've implemented our custom matcher for responses with custom date range.

Answer (score 0):

Use this after you have return response:

```
$xav = new \Ups\AddressValidation(UPSAccessKey, UPSUserId, UPSPassword);
$xav->activateReturnObjectOnValidate(); //This is optional
try {
       $response = $xav->validate($address, $requestOption = 
       \Ups\AddressValidation::REQUEST_OPTION_ADDRESS_VALIDATION, $maxSuggestion = 5);
       if ($response->isValid()) {
                $response->validAddress = true;
                $response->suggestedAddress =  $response->getCandidateAddressList();
       }
```

it will help you.